# Simple issue Writing from array to text file after storing what I have read as array and editing one of the arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Simple issue with writing back from array to text file after storing what I have read as array and editing one of the arrays.
I need to write all the information back from the array into the text file.

I have read all the text and they are stored as variable[] called scores.

I want to write this back with new scores for one of the players

I have the players name in a text box on my form

My text file consists of 
playername, 
lowscore 
highscore,
blank space line inbetween
Then three more players in this format.

```
                        scores = File.ReadAllLines(Source);
                        int counter = 0;
                        List<Score> Results = new List<Score>();

                        while (counter < scores.Length)
                        {
                            Score scor = new Score();
                            scor.Name = scores[counter];
                            int.TryParse(scores[counter + 1], out scor.low);
                            int.TryParse(scores[counter + 2], out scor.high);
                            counter += 3;
                        }

                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Source);
                        while (m_SelectedItem == Name)
                        {
                         //In here I need help
                        }
```

Comment: instead of an array create a class to contain all the related data; then perhaps a list of them (if there is more than one player or whatever at a time); then serialize *all* the players/items/scores at once in less code.

Comment: You're not storing the "scor" that you create anywhere....so you're losing all the data that you parsed from your file.

Comment: The only code you've shown appears to parse the input, and you don't even show any code that _uses_ that parsed input. You also didn't show the code that "edits" the array (i.e. changes its contents). Finally, you didn't explain what you've tried so far, what it did, and how that was different from what you wanted. From the incomplete code example it seems you _might_ just need to call `sw.WriteLine()` three times for each item you want to write out, but there's not really enough context here to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help big time.Much apprieciated all your input. I will need to store that scor lol. Il work on it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add some stuff to the end of the text file, use `File.AppendAllLines(Source,score);` If you want to edit something in the middle of the text file, is there a reason you can't just overwrite the whole file? So after you've edited the scores (I'm assuming the edited scores are all in the Results list?) do something like this:

```
List<string> NewScores=new List<string>();
foreach(Score score in Results){
    NewScores.Add(score.Name);
    NewScores.Add(score.low);
    NewScores.Add(score.high);
    NewScores.Add("");
}
File.WriteAllLines(Source,NewScores.ToArray());
```

I'd store data like this in an XML file rather than text. That will allow you to easily sort, edit and query the data, and allow node-based navigation of the data which is what you seem to be trying to do here. I think the [C# XML tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) are pretty easy to learn.

Comment: Yeah I had it working through a database access file originally it worked fine. However the lecture has changed the specification to be from a text file because my college didnt have the drivers installed to access database for visual studio 2012. Only for the previous versions. And we cannot use SQL because thats the next module. If the scores low and high are int values is it much different because its saying that they are overloading because of this.